# How to create a module as a wrapper for js

Tags: 7, javascript

I do a lot of theming but I don't have much in the way of php skills. So when I use or create a cool piece of javascript, I put it into my theme layer. The problem is, 90% of the time it doesn't belong there, and I really can't share what I've done with others.

So, how can I create a module, basically as a wrapper, for js code? I need to know more about that basic custom module structure and also the php used to insert js and css. Bonus would be basic info about creating blocks, content types and views with the module rather than creating them on the site UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've done work with themes and template.php, writing a module will be a snap. Review [Creating Drupal 7.x modules](http://drupal.org/node/361112) for the basics, but at a minimum you need a *yourmodulename*.info and a *yourmodulename*.module file to get going. [Declaring the block](http://drupal.org/node/1104464)
 specifically will start you off on being able to define your blocks. As for including css and js, use the [drupal_add_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) and [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) functions respectively.